# how to check voice of speech recognition man or woman

Tags: java, android

I am a developer of Android and I want to input speech in the application and convert the speech input to the text and compare it with another text I have also want to know the voice of entrance the speech Is he a man or a woman

Comment: This is a very broad question. You need to provide the code that you've been working with and the specific problem you are having. In other words, you need to do some research first. Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The best approach would probably be using machine learning for this . https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ali_Cibikdiken/publication/312219824_Voice_Gender_Recognition_Using_Deep_Learning/links/59f05fb90f7e9beabfc6757a/Voice-Gender-Recognition-Using-Deep-Learning.pdf . But you can't expect a detailed answer here since the effort you put into writing the question doesn't seem appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's kinda difficult, even for humans it's not 100%

The only solution I can think of is a database of different voices, a folder for male voice and another for female, by comparing your input voice with the different voices in the database you may get a close answer to your request, the only problem is with the execution time

Comment: Oh my God, I had a very nice idea :'(

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to determine gender based on voice alone. There are women with very deep voices and men with very high pitch voices.

You will need to have the user enter this information manually.

Comment: Oh my God, I had a very nice idea